# ESRI Shapefile --> Halliburton GeoGraphix .cdf via Data interoperability

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fme-form, data-interoperability, plss

I'm building a landgrid Public Land Survey System (PLSS) file for the state of Oklahoma using ArcMap and the data interoperability extension for use in LMKR's GeoGraphix. I've downloaded section grid for the state in the form of a shapefile, ran a quick export, generating the file format below.

I was able to import the file into GeoGraphix, but the relevant information needed to populate the GeoGraphix database is not imported with the file, and the features are drawn as quarries or mines and not sections.

After doing some research on the GeoGraphix file format, I came across this table which explains how the software reads the import file (attached below).

I then when into ArcMap and ran another quick export of a township, imported the .cdf into GeoGraphix and manually populated the database information for the imported sections. After getting everything populated and identified, I exported the file out of GeoGraphix as a .cdf resulting in the below format.

[image]

Where [B3001010] Tells GeoGraphix that it is a PLSS section feature [6] meridian [30.0]township [S]Township Direction [15.0] range [W] range direction [33] section number. followed by the coordinates for this feature.

Being that the shapefile contains all the information above as fields, its it possible to build a date interoperability model to convert the information stored in their respective fields into a string in the correct format so GeoGraphix can recognize the and import the file correctly.
[image]

I realize most people might not be familiar with GeoGraphix or the .cdf format, but I hope that people familiar with the data interoperability extension could lend enough advice to help me out.

Comment: Trying to do the exact same thing. Have you made any progress on this matter?

Comment: I've just added a tag for FME because I think what you are looking at is an FME Workbench being accessed via the ArcGIS Data Interoperability extension.